# Ionic displaying audio stream from an API

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I was given two urls, the first one is for the live stream radio and the second one is for the API respectively as following:

The actual stream [link](http://116.202.174.106:8100/live).

Here's the API for the stream:

```
{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"kind":"Rotblau\\Model\\FcbLiveRadio\\Stream","items":[{"id":1,"url":"http:\/\/116.202.174.106:8100\/live","type":"LIVE","name":"Live-Studio"}]}}
```

I've been trying to use all available Audio packages for Ionic like **StreamingMedia**, **NativeAudio**, and Media but it seems like all of these are outdated or so, every time I try to call a method like play() on a test mp3 it does nothing and I get a bunch of errors. **So I need a working package or modern way to display that audio stream on the page if it's possible**.